# spring security: user -> user_type -> permission

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I am new to spring, I would like to ask if the setup below is possible with spring-security:

- USER->USER_TYPE->PERMISSION
  User has User Type;
  A User Type has Permission(s);

Honestly, I've been reading ACL but still I am not sure if I can use it to this type of setup.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring Security the nomenclature is USER => GROUP => AUTHORITY. ACLs are a even more granular method of handling authorization which I believe is unnecessary for your described use case.

There is a pre-defined [database schema](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-schema) for storing this information as well as a `UserDetailsService` [implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html) for populating your security context/principal.  Look at the documentation on [Authority Groups](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#authority-groups) for more information.